# Creating line that passes a point

Tags: point, line, parallel-lines, perpendicular

I am going to draw a polygon around each crosswalk in a city. The problem is that I have a point in the middle of each crosswalk but I need to have a line so that I can make a buffer around it to cover the crosswalk area.
Is there any way to convert each point to a line that crosses the mentioned crosswalk? Or any way to draw a line that crosses through the point that I already have for each crosswalk?

Comment: If you know the size (length and width) and direction of each crosswalk, yes.

Comment: To be able to answer, you should provide a bit more details, especially what kind of data do you have. To create a polygon from  point, we neet to know where from we know 1) the angle (direction) from the point of the crosspass (to create the line) 2) the width of the crosspass (to get the size of the buffer). Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 
The data that I have is a point layer each of them is in the middle of a crosspass. Now I want to first create a line that crosses the point that I have.